# How to exclude properties files when packaging Mule 4 project

Tags: maven, mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have a project on Mule Runtime 4.2.2 and I am working on AnypointStudio.

Now I am trying to exclude dev.properties file from `src/main/resources` folder when packaging. Because I am using prod.properties on a production. But for some reason nothing works. It keeps showing up in .jar file.

Here is what I did:

1) Created a new file in the project folder named "_muleExclude"

2) Added exclusion rule:
`dev.properties`. Also tried `**/src/main/resources/dev.properties`

3) Packaged with `mvn clean package`

I am using mule-maven-plugin version 3.3.5. Found only this documentation about _muleExclude:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/package-a-mule-application#exclude-files-from-the-application-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be working. It could be a bug.

Comment: Yes, I tried before writing my response. I didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but It took me a while to find the solution and this question popped up really high in my searches about the exclude file not working. So, I'm answering here for anyone else looking for a solution.

Mulesoft put out an article in Jan 2021 addressing the issue of excluding files from the src/main/resources.

> The resources found in the src/main/resources folder are included in maven by default.

Because of this you need to tell maven directly to exclude them using the pom.xml.

> In order to exclude the file named "application-dev.yaml" located
> inside the directory src/main/resources/ in this app, you should add
> this to the  section of your pom.xml file

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/application-dev.yaml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Source: https://mulesoftprm.force.com/s/article/Unable-to-Exclude-Files-Inside-src-main-resources-Directory-With-Mule-Maven-Plugin-3-x

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${jdk.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>add-resource</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-resource</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Add the path which needs to be in artifact.

Comment: I didn't get it. I think `src/main/resources` is read by default and I dont need to manually add that package. My problem here is that mule just ignores `_muleExclude` file